# Tablayout ViewPager2 going to last page when click on tab no. >3

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am implementing ViewPager2 + TabLayout. In Java the similar code worked fine but in Kotlin I am having a problem. when I select Tab greater than 3 the viewpager2 sets the page(Fragment) in the last position. Swiping the page in the viewpager shows the correct page also selecting the 1st,2nd, and 3rd Tab in Tablayout shows navigate to the correct page.

I had put a log in Adapter to check the position it prints all positions one by one.

Adapter Class

```
class ViewPager2Adapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private val fragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        Log.e("TAG",position.toString() )
        return fragmentList[position]

    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    fun add(s: Fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(s)

    }
}
```

Fragment from where i am setting the Viewpager

```
 fun setupTabLayout() {
       
        val home = activity as HomeDash

        val myAdapter = ViewPager2Adapter(this.getChildFragmentManager() , this.lifecycle)
        var  FragmentNameList:Array<String>
        
            myAdapter.addFragment(StatisticsFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(ApprovalFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(ProfessionalDetailsFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(PersonalDetailsFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(EducationalDetailsFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(BankDetailsFragmnt())
            myAdapter.addFragment(SalaryDetailsFragment())
            myAdapter.addFragment(LoanFragment())


             FragmentNameList = arrayOf(
                "Statistics",
                "Approval",
                "Professional Details",
                "Personal Details",
                "Educational Details",
                "Bank Details",
                "Salary Details",
                "Loan Details",
            )
        
        
        viewbinding.tabPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL)

        viewbinding.tabPager.setAdapter(myAdapter)


        TabLayoutMediator(viewbinding.fragmentTabLayout, viewbinding.tabPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = FragmentNameList[position]
            //viewbinding.tabPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)

        }.attach()


    }
```

Log

```
2023-10-23 17:00:01.125  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  0
2023-10-23 17:00:02.534  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  1
2023-10-23 17:00:02.550  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  On create 
2023-10-23 17:00:02.876  3752-3764  System                  gen.reporting_mvvm                   W  A resource failed to call close. 
2023-10-23 17:00:02.916  3752-3752  RecyclerView            gen.reporting_mvvm                   W  No adapter attached; skipping layout
2023-10-23 17:00:03.183  3752-3752  RecyclerView            gen.reporting_mvvm                   W  No adapter attached; skipping layout
2023-10-23 17:00:03.187  3752-3752  View                    gen.reporting_mvvm                   D  [ANR Warning]onLayout time too long, this =androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{9f12e4b VFED..... ......ID 54,48-1026,1579 #7f0a00a1 app:id/RecyclerApproval}time =629 ms
2023-10-23 17:00:03.187  3752-3752  View                    gen.reporting_mvvm                   D  [ANR Warning]onLayout time too long, this =androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{cdc028 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1611}time =630 ms
2023-10-23 17:00:03.187  3752-3752  View                    gen.reporting_mvvm                   D  [ANR Warning]onLayout time too long, this =android.widget.FrameLayout{f173141 V.E...... ......ID 1080,0-2160,1611 #3}time =630 ms
2023-10-23 17:00:03.189  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  2
2023-10-23 17:00:04.067  3752-3752  Looper                  gen.reporting_mvvm                   W  PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=1367 plan=17:00:02.518 late=12ms wall=1533ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver procState=-1
2023-10-23 17:00:04.067  3752-3752  Looper                  gen.reporting_mvvm                   W  PerfMonitor doFrame : time=1533ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=12ms procState=-1 historyMsgCount=2
2023-10-23 17:00:04.071  3752-3752  Choreographer           gen.reporting_mvvm                   I  Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-10-23 17:00:04.158  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  3
2023-10-23 17:00:04.620  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  4
2023-10-23 17:00:05.554  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  5
2023-10-23 17:00:06.027  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  6
2023-10-23 17:00:06.872  3752-3752  TAG                     gen.reporting_mvvm                   E  7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabLayoutMediator(viewbinding.fragmentTabLayout, viewbinding.tabPage,true,false) { tab, position ->
tab.text = FragmentNameList[position]
}.attach()

Setting smooth scrolling false solves the problem.